# How to implement iterator that inherit from external package

Tags: python, oop

Let say there is an [external package](https://geoparse.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#) which are can be invoke 
the following way

```
import GEOparse
gse = GEOparse.get_GEO(geo="GSE1563", destdir="./")

# I want to mypackage to inherit this iterator
for gsm_name, gsm in gse.gsms.iteritems():
   pass
```

Then I am making my own package which aim to wrap that external package and possibly later adding more functions.

**mypackage.py**

```
import GEOparse
def load(geoid=None, destdir=None, filepath=None):
   if filepath:
      GEOparse.get_GEO(filepath=filepath)
   else:
      GEOparse.get_GEO(geo=geoid, destdir=destdir)
   return
```

Now with this test code I'm calling `mypackage` without any problem

**test_code.py**

```
import mypackage
mygse = mypackage.load(filepath="./GSE74306.soft.gz")
```

My question is how can implement the iterator `gse.gsm.iteritems` inside `mypackage`. And how can I invoke that from `test_code.py`?
I'm thinking to do something like:

```
for foo, bar in mygse.my_gsms_function.iteritems():
   pass
```

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you asking how to implement an iterable object?

Comment: @Bakuriu: Correct. *Implement iterable object that inherit from other package* to be specific.

Comment: Then your question may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols

Comment: @Bakuriu: No. It doesn't tell you how to inherit from other package.

Comment: Then your question is how to subclass? I believe you have to clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve and where is the problem; as it stands your question is quite broad.